# DD4T GenericComponentFactory obsolete content

Tags: dd4t, 2013-sp1

We are facing caching issue when we fetch Dynamic Component using DD4T’s getComponent function of GenericComponentFactory class. We are getting old data even after the content is updated and published.
We tried the following to overcome this issue, but it still persists.

1. Removing caching from web application. Restarting the application also gives the old values so probably it’s not related to web-application side caching.
2. Removed caching from cd_storage_conf.xml file in app and broker deployer.
3. Using NoCacheProvider in dispatcher servlet.

We are usign dd4t 1.31 api
Note: Directly hitting the broker via broker-query gives the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable your cache from storage config in two ways

- Make sure broker DB is correct :)
- You can stop caching at global level `<ObjectCache Enabled="false">` or individually for required item, in your case DCP, in storage config.
- You may have to optimize following parameters or other settings mentioned at following

  ```
  cache.dependency.ttl = 20
  Cache.expired.ttl = 20
  cache.ttl = 20
  ```

  you can refer this [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/content-not-changing-in-dd4t) for more settings.

Comment: Thanks,, I already did these as mentioned in question too.

Comment: did you check the link?

Comment: if this is something live, check CDN/Akamai

Comment: its is dev.... No CDN is configured yet

Comment: have you gone through this http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/content-not-changing-in-dd4t

Comment: That was raised by me only few months back... That issue was something diffferent then posted this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35012/discussion-between-raj-kumar-and-harish-sharma).